# React Native Navigator transition issue

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple RN app, when I call navigator.push({...}) to navigate to a different scene, the current scene slides out towards left, and the new scene slides in from right. The problem is the current scene slides much slower (seems it only moves about 1/4 of the screen width) than the new scene, so the new scene actually catches up and overlaps with the current scene before the current scene disappears.

Any idea on how to fix this?

RN version: 0.34
Navigator (**not** NavigatorIOS)

I am running the app in simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When testing animations and performance you should ensure that you are not using chrome debugger or devtools. The reason it is slow is because you are running the app JavaScript on a completely different machine and there is a lot of overhead to passing messages back and forth.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5632

You can also set Development mode to false and see if it makes a difference.

> JavaScript thread performance suffers greatly when running in dev mode. This is unavoidable: a lot more work needs to be done at runtime to provide you with good warnings and error messages, such as validating propTypes and various other assertions.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html

Comment: Thanks @Lian, in my case the remote debugging was never turned on. the animation is actually very smooth.  just that the sliding out scene only moves 1/4 of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out and it's my own fault -
I turns out the scene on its way out is supposed to move about 1/4 screen width. The scene on its way in 'catches up' and cover the scene on its way out.

My problem was that my second view does not have backgroundColor set, so it became transparent so the content of both scenes 'blended' and looks wrong.