# ListView in React-Native( iOS ) not running smooth

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

It looks like my ListView has a problem, it's not running smooth;

The Code :

```
class ZpRNProj extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super() ;

    let contentArr = [
  'fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','end01',
  'fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','end02',
  'fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','fdsfdfs','end03',] ;
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}) ;
    this.state = {dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(contentArr)}
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) =>{
        return <Text>{rowData}-{sectionID}-{rowID}-{highlightRow}</Text>
      }}
    >
    </ListView>
    ) ;

  }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ZpRNProj', () => ZpRNProj);
```

I found that the App run time frame dropping.

Why is this happening? Thanks .

Comment: what do you mean by 'dropped frame'?

Comment: Very card . Running is not smooth

Comment: @user5465320 please be more specific with your question. We actually don't understand what dropped frame means. Everything looks fine with your ListView. Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696857/react-native-navigator-transition-issue/39703314#39703314). I explain there, why animations sometimes does not look smooth maybe thats your problem.

Comment: @user5465320 what do you mean by 'very card'?

Comment: @LianvanderVyver thanks very much . (Im sorry my english is so pool)

Comment: @JanFranzPalngipang Im sorry my english is so pool